# jQuery iframe selector workings in dev tool but not in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone tell me why the following line works from the dev tool console but does not work in the page, I keep getting length as 0

```
$("iframe[name='gridFrame']").contents().find("form[name='grid']").length;
```

This is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(function () {
        submitThis();

        function submitThis() {
            var a = $("iframe[name='gridFrame']").contents().find("form[name='grid']").length;
            console.log(a);
        }
     })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe name="gridFrame" src="temp-iframe-test.html">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the iframe file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
   <form name="grid">
     <input id="fname" />
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your submitThis() function is firing before your iframe has loaded its source. That is why you see a length of 0.

Try adding:
    onload="submitThis()" to your iframe element and moving your submitThis function into global scope (out of the $ function).

When using the dev console, your iframe has since loaded its file.

Comment: What if I don't want to submit form on frame load instead want it to trigger with some action in the main window?